# Trying to extract data from website into Excel. For loop not working

Tags: vba, excel, extract

I am trying to extract data about NFL recruits from the following website:

```
http://espn.go.com/college-sports/football/recruiting/rankings/_/class/2013
```

I need to access every single position and copy paste/ extract the information into an Excel spreadsheet. As you can see below, the only difference in the URL for each of these positions is the VARIABLE in caps. I need this VARIABLE to change from athlete to cornerbacks to wide-receiver.

```
http://espn.go.com/college-sports/football/recruiting/playerrankings/_/position/VARIABLE/class/2013/view/position
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
Dim array_example(18) As String

Sub Macro1()


        array_example(0) = "athlete"
        array_example(1) = "cornerback"
        array_example(2) = "defensive-end"
        array_example(3) = "defensive-tackle"
        array_example(4) = "fullback"
        array_example(5) = "inside-linebacker"
        array_example(6) = "kicker"
        array_example(7) = "offensive-center"
        array_example(8) = "offensive-guard"
        array_example(9) = "outside-linebacker"
        array_example(10) = "offensive-tackle"
        array_example(11) = "quarterback-dual-threat"
        array_example(12) = "quarterback-pocket-passer"
        array_example(13) = "running-back"
        array_example(14) = "safety"
        array_example(15) = "tight-end-h"
        array_example(16) = "tight-end-y"
        array_example(17) = "wide-receiver"

        For i = 0 To 17

            LastUsedRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(Sheet1.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

            LastEmptyRow = LastUsedRow + 1

            Cell = "A" & LastEmptyRow


            With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://espn.go.com/college-sports/football/recruiting/playerrankings/_/position/" & array_example(i) & "/class/2013/view/position" & "", Destination:=Range("" & Cell & ""))
                .Name = "s"
                .FieldNames = True
                .RowNumbers = True
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertEntireCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
                .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
                .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
                .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = False
                .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
                .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
                .WebDisableRedirections = False
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True


            End With

        Next i

End Sub
```

My problem is that everytime I run this code, excel gets stuck (there is this little circular disk that keeps rotating for the cursor). When I press Escape to stop the code, I find that there is only one position that has been copied to the Excel Spreadsheet. Can you please take a look at my code and let me know what I can change for it to loop through all of the positions and copy all of the information (one after another) into the spreadsheet?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: I tried your code and it's working

Comment: did you get all the observations? or was it only about 100 ( as measure by rank? When i tried i only got 100 for 1 position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I first ran the code I had the same experience that you described.  I waited about 2 minutes and killed the process to find that only the first 100 where loaded.

I went in and changed this line to `false` so that I could see it loading.

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

---

I also added a debug line before `Next i` so I can watch if it actually iterates through all addresses.

```
    End With
  Debug.Print "next " & i
Next i
```

---

Now when I ran it it only took about 30 seconds and completed all 18 addresses.  The results where over 3000 rows in excel.

I then added a simple timer to see how long each step took.  This time it only took 12 seconds total.

```
next 0 - 0 seconds
next 1 - 1 seconds
next 2 - 1 seconds
next 3 - 1 seconds
next 4 - 0 seconds
next 5 - 0 seconds
next 6 - 3 seconds
next 7 - 1 seconds
next 8 - 0 seconds
next 9 - 1 seconds
next 10 - 0 seconds
next 11 - 0 seconds
next 12 - 2 seconds
next 13 - 1 seconds
next 14 - 0 seconds
next 15 - 0 seconds
next 16 - 1 seconds
next 17 - 0 seconds
Total Time: 12
```

---

Next, changed the backgroundQuery back to true.  The timer counted through all 18 in less than 1 second and only the first 100 results displayed.  It was like excel was running through the code before all the connections where being set so it only had enough time to set the first one.

So, I'd suggest just setting the background query to false.  The time ran between 12 and 30 seconds each time I tried.

Here you can see that it made it all the way through wide receiver.

[image]

---

***NESTED LOOP QUESTION***

Write the outer loop as your year loop.  So before `For i = 0 To 17` add this:

```
  For x = 2006 to 2013
    For i = 0 To 17

     '...continue your code

     ' Change With line to this:
     With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://espn.go.com/college-sports/football/recruiting/playerrankings/_/position/" & array_example(i) & "/class/" & CStr(x) & "/view/position" & "", Destination:=Range("" & Cell & ""))

     '...continue your code

   Next i
  Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked great for me. I am now on my way to copying the database for years 2006- 2014.

Comment: Portland Runner, thanks once again for your help. I not only need to cycle through each year but I also need to direct the data for each year into separate work sheets. For instance, I would like all data points from the year 2003 in sheet1 and all the data points from year 2004 in sheet2. Is there a way to include this information in the nested loop that you mentioned above? I was trying to mess with the "With" line by changing ActiveSheet to a variable that changed from one sheet to another for each x but the With line would not accept a variable or a string in place of ActiveSheet

Comment: Yes it can be done.  Do you want the sheet named with the current year or are they existing sheets with different names?

Comment: I would like the sheets to be named with the current year. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.  Maybe you have a slow/no internet connection to get the data.

This is what it looks like

[image: Excel Page]

I'm getting 100 WRs.  If I run the loop just the first time and I stop it I get 100 ATH.

It looks like your for loop is running and putting your `QueryTable` in one row and then before the data fills it puts the next one a single row below it, possibly overwriting it. I would put each one in a separate Worksheet instead.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Can you please let me know if you got all the observations? If yes, how long did it take? When I checked, I only got upto 100 observations ( as measured by rank). I was hoping to get about 100 observations for all positions which would add up to around 900 obs. Please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I need all the data for one year (which is 2013 in this case) in a single worksheet. Preferable, I would like the observations for one position to be filled in followed by another position in the rows preceding it. Do you know of a way to make this happen?

Comment: @SidharthMoktan If you know for sure there will only be 100 then you can space the tables every 110 rows.  That's not very programmatic though.  Your way of searching for the last row and moving up is the way to go, except you need to wait for each QueryTable to finish prior to going to the next. There is no refreshing property (in excel vba) that I can find to know to stop waiting though.

Comment: Do you think it would help if I used a timing delay? I was looking around in StackOverflow and came across the following command.    Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")). Could I place it after the End With statement for about 10 seconds?

Comment: I guess you could but you don't know how long it will take. What if the connection is slow one particular time?  I don't have a great solution.  But your best bet would be either to wait for the query to finish refreshing or space the rows based on knowledge of the size of the data. @Portland Runner s answer looks promising